# How can I programmatically access tasks in hotmail?

Tags: hotmail, activesync

I would like to be able to programmatically access Hotmail tasks so I can keep resetting the reminder until the task is marked as complete.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I have seen that there is a Hotmail API here: http://isdk.dev.live.com/?mkt=en-us
but I haven't seen where you can access the task information only the calendar.

I have also seen that Hotmail uses Active Sync so I am guessing it is possible to write an Active Sync client to be able to retrieve task information (please correct me if I am wrong about this), I found more information about that here: [ActiveSync library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585025/activesync-library/4673798#4673798) and [How do I implement activesync protocol in iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075404/how-do-i-implement-activesync-protocol-in-iphone-app/5075450#5075450).  Some people have suggested using [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx), but from what I read Hotmail doesn't support this.

Thanks
Grant